# How to prevent SQL injection attack in SOAP/REST services?

Tags: rest, web-services, security, soap, sql-injection

We have tested our web services for security concerns. Our security audit team identified issue of SQL query (Sleep command) injection. Team intercepted the SOAP/rest request further inserted  the time based sql query in input field. As result of which our service is responding after specified time interval.

Please suggest ways to prevent this sql injection in soap/rest request.

Comment: Do you use plain SQL or ORM to manage data?

Comment: Thanks for reply .we use Hibernate for db operations.

Comment: MySQL? Do you use plain SQL or Hibernate Criteria / prepared statements?

Comment: Check this: https://blog.pythian.com/mysql-injection-sleep/